# Is there a way to scroll on a site that uses virtual scroll in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright, e2e, virtualscroll

I'm attempting to scroll on a page that has virtual scrolling, but it doesn't seem to scroll at all. If I disable virtual scrolling on the site it will start to scroll correctly using:

`await page.locator('data-testid=row', {hasText: 'someText'}).click();`

However, if there is virtual scroll enabled that will no longer work and it will wait forever in debug mode.

Does Playwright support Virtual Scrolling?

And if it does, does anyone know a way to make it scroll when virtual scrolling is enabled?